# WMS 1.1.1 CQL Filter "IN" Keyword not working

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

I have a question with using "in" keyword on WMS cql_filter.

```
cql_filter    STRSUBSTRING(UPLOAD_DATE, 4, 6) = '01'
It works. however..

cql_filter    STRSUBSTRING(UPLOAD_DATE, 4, 6) IN ('01', '02', '03')
It doesn't work.

UPLOAD_DATE COLUMN DATAS examples

20210112<br/>
20211113<br/>
20210909
```

How can i use 'in' keyword on wms 1.1.1?